# Can not get key value from maxmind return object

Tags: php, maxmind

I am using maxmind web service to get the user data:

Here is the PHP code to output the data.

Now here you can see I have commented out i**p_address, user_type, is_anonymous, is_anonymous_proxy, is_anonymous_vpn, is_tor_exit_node** key **because** I can't get value using those keys?

can you tell me why?

```
$client = new Client( client number , 'my license keyu');       
// Call insights method to get full details        
$record = $client->insights( '103.82.11.26' ); 

//$result['ipAddress']         = $record->traits->ip_address;
$result['country']           = $record->country->name;
$result['city']              = $record->city->name;
//$result['userType']          = $record->traits->user_type;
$result['isp']               = $record->traits->isp;
$result['organization']      = $record->traits->organization;
$result['network']           = $record->traits->network;
//$result['isAanonymous']      = $record->traits->is_anonymous;
//$result['isAnonymous_proxy'] = $record->traits->is_anonymous_proxy;
//$result['isAnonymous_vpn']   = $record->traits->is_anonymous_vpn;
//$result['isTorExitNode']     = $record->traits->is_tor_exit_node;
$result['referer']           = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$result['userAgent']         = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

but If I do

```
print_r( $record );
```

I can see full object containing all the data.

**Updated**

Actual Object that is return https://codeshare.io/ad3nVy

Comment: if you can share the print($record) .. just the keys would be sufficient

Comment: @SandeepKothari okay. I am sharing it.

Comment: @SandeepKothari I have updated my questions or check this https://codeshare.io/ad3nVy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the names as per these keys:

```
 [0] => autonomousSystemNumber
                    [1] => autonomousSystemOrganization
                    [2] => connectionType
                    [3] => domain
                    [4] => ipAddress
                    [5] => isAnonymous
                    [6] => isAnonymousProxy
                    [7] => isAnonymousVpn
                    [8] => isHostingProvider
                    [9] => isLegitimateProxy
                    [10] => isp
                    [11] => isPublicProxy
                    [12] => isSatelliteProvider
                    [13] => isTorExitNode
                    [14] => network
                    [15] => organization
                    [16] => staticIpScore
                    [17] => userCount
                    [18] => userType
                )
```

So, basically for example:

$record->traits->ipAddress

Comment: You Right, but how do you know that I need to use these keys?

Comment: By the response ... actually in the response if you see that record element that has traits key has all those attributes that you need... also, it looks like the shared response is altered.. if you can check the fresh response you can see the keys